# JDK 1.8 GeneXus X Ev. 2

Tags: java, winforms, compilação, aplicação-web, genexus

Gostaria de saber se o **GeneXus X Ev.2** ou superior já permite compilar os programas gerados em Java com o JDK 1.8.

Tenho que fazer algo diferente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funciona sem problemas com o JDK 1.8. Basta alterar as propriedades do gerador para apontar para o JDK 1.8 ao invés do 1.7 ou 1.6.

Ver http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Category%3AGeneXus+Java+Generator,

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sim, responde sim. Programas gerados pelo GeneXus X Evolution 2 podem sim ser compilados com o JDK 1.8. Basta alterar as propriedades do gerador para apontar para o JDK 1.8 ao invés do 1.7 ou 1.6.

Comment: Paulo, bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Sua resposta realmente responde à pergunta, que é muito simples, mas sem o link ficava um pouco vaga, sem embasamento. Agora já está melhor. Procure sempre dar respostas mais completas, citando referências quando pertinente, e evite ser muito curto, caso contrário pode passar a imagem que você está respondendo sem conhecimento e os usuários podem votar negativamente por considerarem uma resposta de "baixa qualidade". Leia [*como escrever uma boa resposta*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) na nossa Central de Ajuda. ;)